# Extract rows from python array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `X` with shape `(768, 8)`.

The last value for each row can either be `0` or `1`, I only want rows with value `1`, and call this `T`.

I did:

```
T = [x for x in X if x[7]==1]
```

This is correct, however, this is now a list, not a numpy array (in fact I cannot print `T.shape`).

What should I do instead to keep this a numpy array?

Comment: Why not just `T = np.array(T)` ??

Comment: Ok, so just keep the code for T and transform it back to a numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy's boolean indexing gets the job done in a fully vectorized manner. This approach is generally more efficient (and arguably more elegant) than using list comprehensions and type conversions.

```
T = X[X[:, -1] == 1]
```

Demo:

```
In [232]: first_columns = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 7))

In [233]: last_column = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 1))

In [234]: X = np.hstack((first_columns, last_column))

In [235]: X
Out[235]: 
array([[4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 0],
       [2, 7, 9, 4, 7, 1, 8, 0],
       [9, 8, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5, 1],
       [4, 4, 4, 9, 6, 4, 9, 1],
       [9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 4, 9, 0],
       [8, 3, 3, 2, 9, 5, 5, 1],
       [7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 7, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 1, 5, 2, 6, 0],
       [7, 9, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 1],
       [3, 1, 8, 7, 3, 2, 9, 0]])

In [236]: mask = X[:, -1] == 1

In [237]: mask
Out[237]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [238]: T = X[mask]

In [239]: T
Out[239]: 
array([[9, 8, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5, 1],
       [4, 4, 4, 9, 6, 4, 9, 1],
       [8, 3, 3, 2, 9, 5, 5, 1],
       [7, 9, 9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 1]])
```

Comment: You can also use X.compress(mask, axis=0) for a more explicit / less-overhead. If using row indices instead of a mask you can use X.take(rowxs, axis=0). Numpy's fancy indexing calls these functions under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

By calling

```
T = [x for x in X if x[8]==1]
```

you are making `T` as a list. To convert it any list to a numpy array, just use:

```
T = numpy.array([x for x in X if x[8]==1])
```

Here is what happens:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 

In [2]: a = [1,2,3,4]

In [3]: a.T
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9f69ed463660> in <module>()
----> 1 a.T

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'

In [4]: a = np.array(a)

In [5]: a.T
Out[5]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [6]:
```

Comment: Ok, so I need the intermediate passage to a list and back to a numpy matrix. There is no direct conversion.

Comment: @user: Check the edit. You can just say, `numpy.array([x for x in X if x[8]==1])`

Comment: Yes, that is the same. I was just wondering if there was a preferred numpy operation. Anyway, this works, thanks.